# how to select the value from list pair in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

i have below list, trying to pull the value of the list pair, example i need to know what is the `average_buy_price` from the `list`.

```
[{'enabled': True, 'total_buy_quantity': 45, 'average_buy_price': '6755.03'}]
```

currently it is giving `error`.

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

the above output is coming from system, i  need to select only the value which i need. example `( 'average_buy_price')` need to get the output of the value. `'6755.03`

one thing i have notice is that, it is starting with [ and closing with ] , for testing i just copied from { to } i am able to pull the value, looks like some problem with syntax when i am using. required help.

Comment: `float(your_list[0].get('average_buy_price'))`

Comment: "currently it is giving ``error``" – The "code" as shown is just a literal declaration. It does not throw any error. Please show a [mcve] of what you are actually doing, so that we can help with it.

Comment: `[]` delimits a `list` literal, `{}` is delimiting a `dict` literal in this case. You haven't provided a [MCVE], so we can only guess what you're doing wrong, but for starters, I'd guess you're trying to do `thelist['average_buy_price']`, which won't work; `thelist[0]['average_buy_price']` would (indexing the `list` to get the `dict`, then looking up a value in the `dict`), but any more than that needs a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you list there is a single `dictionary`. To access `average_buy_price` from the dict try:

```
test_list = [{'enabled': True, 'total_buy_quantity': 45, 'average_buy_price': '6755.03'}]
print(test_list[0].get('average_buy_price')) # output 6755.03
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, i required one help, can you please share one more example for below code. {'status': 'success', 'message': '', 'data': {'positions': [{'enabled': True, 'close_price': 0.0, 'sell_amount': 304122.6,}]}} ...... i need to print sell_amount value, in single line command.

Comment: Hi, great to know the answer helped you. you can upvote the answer too if you want. here is an example to get sell_amount from your given dict:


`sample_list = {'status': 'success', 'message': '', 'data': {'positions': [{'enabled': True, 'close_price': 0.0, 'sell_amount': 304122.6,}]}}`

`print(sample_list['data'].get('positions')[0].get('sell_amount'))` `output: 304122.6`

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have a list containing a single dictionary. If you want to access the elements of the dictionary, first index the list: `test_list[0]['average_buy_price']`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as you have the square brackets, it's a `list`, and so it cannot be indexed with a string.

Get rid of the square brackets (and retain only the curly braces). It is then no longer a `list`, but a **dictionary**, which can be indexed with the string key value.

Answer (score 0):

Each element of your list is actually a dictionary. So, iterate through the list, then get the key, value pair.

```
myList= [{'enabled': True, 'total_buy_quantity': 45, 'average_buy_price': '6755.03'}]
for d in myList:
    for k, v in d.items():
        print(k,': ',v)
```

**Output:**

```
enabled :  True
total_buy_quantity :  45
average_buy_price :  6755.03
```